# How to add an element to a spinner, Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, oop, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am building an android application with Xamarin.Android which used to be a Windows CE app. I have this little piece of code that is supposed to loop through an array from a different project class and add the items to the checkbox i.e spinner in Xamarin. Do you know how to do this the best way in Xamarin? Thanks.

```
     docTypes = CommonData.ListDocTypes("E|");
        docTypes.Items.ForEach(dt =>
        {
            cbDocType.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { ID = dt.GetString("Code"), Text = dt.GetString("Code") + " " + dt.GetString("Name") });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `ArrayAdapter` as said in microsoft docs.

These are the two steps.

1. Create the adapter object

   var adapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource (
   this, YOUR DATA, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);

   adapter.SetDropDownViewResource (Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
2. Assign it to spinner

   spinner.Adapter = adapter;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/spinner